# Inserting elements to vector with NA's if needed

Tags: r, vector

Let's imagine vector `c(2,3)`. I want to add to this vector number 4 but at fourth place (so the third one should be empty, filled with NA)

To add number to vector we can simply use `append(c(2,3),4,after=3)`. But then we will end up with vector `c(2,3,4)` instead of `c(2,3,NA,4)` I know that it's expected because that is how append function is working, but is there any simple way how can we solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function :

```
append_at_k <- function(vec, k, value) {
  vec[k] <- value
  vec
}

append_at_k(c(2,3), 4, 4)
#[1]  2  3 NA  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own function with same signature as append, for example:

```
myAppend <- function(x,values,after=length(x)) {
  if(after < length(x)) stop("after must be at least length(x)")
  c(x,rep(NA,after-length(x)),values)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
insert_num <- function(vec, num, pos){
  if(pos == (length(vec)+1)) {vec[pos] = num}
  else{
    vec[(length(vec)+1):(pos-1)] = NA
    vec[pos] = num
  }
  vec
}

v
[1] 2 3
insert_num(v,4,3)
[1] 2 3 4
insert_num(v,4,5)
[1]  2  3 NA NA  4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `replace`

```
append_at_k <- function(vec, k, value) {
    replace(vec, k, value)
 }

append_at_k(c(2,3), 4, 4)
#[1]  2  3 NA  4
```